# Exclude mail health indicator from default /actuator/health endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a Spring Boot application that uses the actuator to have a `/actuator/health` endpoint. I recently added `spring-boot-starter-mail` to the application which automatically adds a health indicator for the mail server so the `/actuator/health` will report DOWN if the mail server is down.

I would like to remove that health indicator from `/actuator/health` itself and have another endpoint `/actuator/health/mail` to get the full status.

I know I can create the extra endpoint by adding this property:

```
management.endpoint.health.group.mail.include=mail
```

But how do I remove `mail` from the default endpoint?

I tried using `management.health.mail.enabled=false`, but then I can't use it in the `/actuator/health/mail` endpoint anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This should works :

1/ Create this Health endpoint extension class :

```java
public class HealthEndpointCustomExtension extends HealthEndpointWebExtension {

    public HealthEndpointCustomExtension(HealthContributorRegistry registry, HealthEndpointGroups groups, Duration slowIndicatorLoggingThreshold) {
        super(registry, groups, slowIndicatorLoggingThreshold);
    }

    @Override
    protected HealthComponent aggregateContributions(ApiVersion apiVersion, Map<String, HealthComponent> contributions, StatusAggregator statusAggregator, boolean showComponents, Set<String> groupNames) {
        Map<String, HealthComponent> newContributions = new HashMap<>(contributions);
        newContributions.remove("mail");
        return super.aggregateContributions(apiVersion, newContributions, statusAggregator, showComponents,  groupNames);
    }
```

*aggregateContributions* method, has its name suggests, does an aggregation of each HealthContributor. By overriding this method you can remove the 'mail' contributor from the aggregated result.

2/ Declare your custom component in a configuration class :

```java
    @Bean
    HealthEndpointWebExtension healthEndpointWebExtension(HealthContributorRegistry healthContributorRegistry, HealthEndpointGroups groups, HealthEndpointProperties properties) {
        return new HealthEndpointCustomExtension(healthContributorRegistry, groups, properties.getLogging().getSlowIndicatorThreshold());
    }
```

Comment: Does this mean that the health check is still performed, but the web endpoint just does not show the result?

Comment: Yes, it's correct

Comment: In complement : the result is not only not shown, it is also not taken into account into the final aggregated result.

Comment: is it possible to remove whole groups instead of single components?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `management.health.mail.enabled=false`. Also note that `actuator/health/mail` will return 404 because it has really been disabled